# Kwantitatieve Methoden

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for one article (Eilers P. H. C., 1987, Asymmetric least squares: New faces of a scatterplot. Kwantitatieve methoden 8, 45-64) and since I was not able to find it for some time, I'm asking for help here. I only got URL of the journal (http://www.vvs-or.nl/km.htm), which doesn't work. So please, if you can provide me with some reference, where I could find it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Joe

Comment: This isn't a reference request, but an #icanhazpdf. Have you tried document delivery at a (your?) university library?

Comment: If nothing else, try to contact the author (now retired) through his old department http://www.erasmusmc.nl/biostatistiek/People/Faculty/.

Comment: apparently:  p.eilers "at" erasmusmc.nl